# Generic type parameter constraint based on other type parameter in the same definition

Tags: c#, generics, constraints

I have type hierarchy defined like this:

```
interface IMyClass
{
}

interface IBase1<T>
{
}

interface IBase2<T>
{
}

interface IMyDerived1 : IBase1<IMyClass>
{
}

class Base1<T, U> : IBase1<T>
    where U : IBase2<T>
{
}

class Base2<T, U> : IBase2<T>
    where U : IBase1<T>
{
}

class Derived1<T, U> : Base1<T, U>, IMyDerived1
    where T : IMyClass
    where U : IBase2<T>
{
}

class Derived2<T, U> : Base2<T, U*>
    where T : IMyClass
    where U : IMyDerived1
{
}
```

but Visual Studio 2008 (.net 3.5 SP1) says that parameter U in parent specifier of Derived2 (marked with *) is not convertible to `IBase1<T>`. Is this solvable?

**EDIT:**

It indeed looks like generics overuse but allows Base1,2 and Derived1,2 to apply operations on supplied types without a casts. Something like this:

```
class MyClass : IMyClass
{}

class MySpecific1 : Derived1<MyClass, MySpecific2>
{
    // use inherited properties and methods of type MyClass here
    // use properties of MySpecific2 returning MyClass without casts
}

class MySpecific2 : Derived2<MyClass, MySpecific1>
{
    // use inherited properties and methods of type MyClass here
    // use properties of MySpecific1 returning MyClass without casts
}
```

Probably this can be solved more elegantly with variance in .net4 but I'm stuck with 3.5 for now.

Comment: At first glance this looks like a variant of co- and contra-variance, though I might be wrong.

Comment: I think it's not solvable. In principle it could be solvable via covariance (in C# 4, not 3.5 anyway), but it would imply making a covariant class, which is not allowed anyway.

Comment: By the way, covariance can be used in .NET 3.5 as well. You just have have to use targeted compiler from .NET 4.

Comment: C# is not the same thing as .NET. C# 4.0 can be used with .NET 3.5. I don't know if variance requires CLR support or not. If it does, then .NET 4.0 _would_ be required.

Comment: please don't repeat tags ("C#") in the title. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Derived2<T, U>: Base2<T, U>
        where T: IMyClass
        where U: IMyDerived1, IBase1<T>
    {
    }
```

Comment: Great solution! I didn't thought of something so simple. Can you explain a little bit? It seems to me that compiler do not consider other constraints while evaluating expression in 'where U'. Is that right?

Comment: As Stefan noted, the constraints in Derived2 don't imply, that U is derived from IBase1<T>. But this is required by Base2.

Answer (score 1):

That hurt my head!

Having a look at it, the problem lies with this definition:

```
interface IMyDerived1 : IBase1<IMyClass>
{
}
```

You've specialised that generic implementation, and then attempted to use with generic arguments later on:

```
class Derived2<T, U> : Base2<T, U>
    where T : IMyClass
    where U : IMyDerived1
{
}
```

Which is invalid.  Not sure if this is correct, but can you make either this change:

```
interface IMyDerived1<T> : IBase1<T>
{
}

class Derived2<T, U> : Base2<T, U>
    where T : IMyClass
    where U : IMyDerived1<T>
{
}
```

That's a complicated hierarchy you're designing there, what will be its use?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, in Derived2, T is not IMyClass, it could be some other class implementing this interface. In Base1, it is specified to be exactly IMyClass. Types with different generic arguments are not compatible in C# 3.0.

For me, this looks a bit like generic overuse. But I can't see the context.